# hide iPad keyboard with "hide button" in lower right

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, hide, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

i want to hide iPad virtual keyboard when user presses "hide keyboard button" in the lower right corner. i've set up my viewcontroller as textFieldView's delegate, but no `textFieldShouldReturn` event doesnt called when i press that button. i also set my viewcontroller as an observer for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` - the same effect, no notification generated.
please, give a clue! i've parsed half of network and haven't found any solutions for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well for starters, **textFieldShouldReturn** is only called when tapping the designated "Return" key, not when tapping the hide keyboard key. you should use the **textFieldWillEndEditing** or **textFieldDidEndEditing** delegate methods.

also, unless i'm mistaken, tapping the hide keyboard button in the lower right corner should hide the keyboard, without any coding necessary on your end.

Comment: thanks for you reply. believe it or not, it was not hiding even i pressed that button. then suddenly it starts operate preperly. i'm confused...